# Several bar plots in same graph in R

Tags: r, bar-chart

I want to show several bar plots on the same graph in R. I used the code, `barplot ()` in R, the color of the bars were selected as `"white"` and the borders were shown in different colors. Since the bars are overlapped, height differences in bars are not shown properly. Instead I want to show the bars without any fill, in a way that the height of every bar is illustrated in the graph. Can anyone please help me with this??

The code I used is here.

```
set.seed (123)
N <- 100
ex_200 <- c (0.0777, 0.0512, 0.0572, 0.0611, 0.0668)
ex.fail_200 <- matrix (NA, ncol = N, nrow = length (ex_200))
for (i in 1: length (ex_200)) {
ex.fail_200 [i, ] <- rpois (N, ex_200 [[i]])
}

counts_200 <- apply (ex.fail_200, 1, table)

barplot (counts_200[[1]], space = 0, col = "white", border = "blue",
 ylim = c (0, 100))
barplot (counts_200[[2]], space = 0, col = "white" , border = "red",
add = TRUE)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use "transparent" as the color instead of white:

```
barplot (counts_200[[1]], space = 0, col = "transparent", border = "blue",
ylim = c (0, 100))
barplot (counts_200[[2]], space = 0, col = "transparent", border = "red",
add = TRUE)
```